# awstats does not detect iphone or ipad from the HTTPD logs

Tags: iphone, awstats, ipad

I'm trying to use awstats to identify number of requests that originated from ipad and iphone. I tried the following URL but none of the steps to recognize ipad/iphone or even iOS work for me:

[Analyze HTTP logs, looking for iOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/248692/analyze-http-logs-looking-for-ios)

I'm using AWStats v7.0 in Linux. Has anyone managed to do this successfully? Thanks!

Comment: It actually worked after some more trying. The answer in the linked post is good!